# Moving a String Array Definition from Main to Another File

Tags: c

I'm writing a game, and right now I'm trying to break up the one file I have into multiple for the sake of organization. I've run into a problem I'm not quite sure how to fix however. Initially, I had a map defined in main like this:

```
char const *map[]={
    " ------------- ",
    "|......|......|",
    "|.............|",
    "|......---.---|",
    "|---.---...|..|",
    "|..........|..|",
    "|..........|..|",
    "|.............|",
    "|..........|..|",
    " ------------- ",
};
```

This was working fine. Now I have moved a declaration into a file called "map.h":

```
extern const char *map[];
```

And the actual definition in a file called "map.c":

```
#include "map.h"
*map = {
    " ------------- ",
    "|......|......|",
    "|.............|",
    "|......---.---|",
    "|---.---...|..|",
    "|..........|..|",
    "|..........|..|",
    "|.............|",
    "|..........|..|",
    " ------------- ",
};
```

This gives me an error: "conflicting types for map"

As well as numerous warnings: "initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types] " ------------- ""

and: "excess elements in scalar initializer" for each row after that.

If I remove the dereference operator in fron of "map" in map.c, then it gives me "initializer element is not computable at load time".
I then thought I could get around this by just defining the array in map.h, but of course this then gives me errors for multiple definitions for each file I include map.h in.

Does anyone know of a way to implement this/what I am doing wrong?

Thanks, Nic

Comment: declaration and definition ftw, in your `map.c`, fix up your declaration of `*map`, it is incorrect.

Comment: Use im map.c const char *map = {

Comment: @t0mm13b Did you mean the definition, as others have suggested? Or is there an error in the declaration?

Comment: @WojtekSurowka I have changed it to that but I'm still getting the same error unfortunately. Wouldn't you just use *map = though, since you have already defined the type for map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your header file `map.h` is fine, even though it should have an include guard. Adding an include guard can be as simple as adding `#pragma once` on its own line at the top of your header file.

Your source file `map.c` has a syntax error that needs to be fixed.

```
const char *map = {
    /* ... */
};
```

Comment: Ah sorry, yes, I didn't include the entire header file. I have

#ifndef H_MAP
#define H_MAP

at the top, closed by an #endif. I changed *map to const char *map as you suggested, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Oh my. I'm not a smart man haha. I realized what I did/what you meant... Thanks for the help!